# Java: Regex: +Quantifier not working

Tags: java, regex

So `"XXXXX**".matches("[X{9,11}\\*{2,3}]")` returns `false` as expected...
But, `"XXXXX**".matches("[X{9,11}\\*{2,3}]+")` returns `true`. Am I using the  `+` quantifier correctly? (I want the second one to also return `false`)

Comment: most symbols lose their meaning in square brackets

Comment: Notable exceptions are `]`, `-` and sometimes `^`, but definitely not `+`.

Comment: `[ ]` is a character class, matching any one of the characters listed between the brackets. Duplicates are ignored. So, `[X{9,11}\*{2,3}]` is the same as `[,{}\*1239X]`, i.e. matching comma, open-brace, close-brace, star, 1, 2, 3, 9, or X. What did you think `[ ]` does?

Comment: If you didn't have the character class, `X{9,11}\*{2,3}` would match between 9 and 11 X's, then 2 or 3 stars. If you wanted to repeat that grouping, you first make it a non-capturing group by wrapping with `(?: )`, then add the `+`, i.e. `(?:X{9,11}\*{2,3})+`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`[...]` matches any character defined in the character class, so 
`[X{9,11}\\*{2,3}]` actually means, a single character which is: X, or open brace, or 9, or comma, or 1, or 1 (yes you have it duplicated), or backslash, or asterisk....

So as your string have more than character in your string to-be-matched, such pattern will not match.

When you add a `+`, it means matching a string with 1 or more [ X or asterisk or....], so it match

I believe what you really want to do is using a group.

So the regex looks like `(X{9,11}\*{2,3}])+`

Comment: Ohhh, *slams forehead on table*, I can't believe I didn't catch that:( Muchos Thank you's!

Answer (score 0):

```
"XXXXXXXXX**".matches("(X{9,11}\\*{2,3})+")
"XXXXXXXX**".matches("(X{9,11}\\*{2,3})+")
```

match true and false.

The whole thing of (Xes and *s) has to occur at least once (+).

No group of characters involved, no need to use '[]'.